# session_start() required for reading $_SESSION

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

Let's say we have index.php which calls `session_start()` and populates `$_SESSION` data.
While the user is on the webpage, they click a button and an AJAX query is kicked off to ajax.php  .
ajax.php does not call `session_start()`, but it is successfully reading the data in `$_SESSION`.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it, but it looks like Niles has an idea.

Comment: If you have a `$_SESSION` with populated data, the session has been started, by you or other code/config.

Comment: ajax requests are just requests like $_REQUEST method, they do not include and merge code, so the behavior is unexpected, but it seems that there's a way to do it, mentioned in the first answer. Honestly I didn't know this directive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the output of a `phpinfo();` call you will probably notice that the `session.auto_start` configuration variable is set to 1.

See [documentation for further reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start). Unless this flag is set it is definitely not expected behaviour, and you are probably including code somewhere that explicitly invokes `session_start()`.

Comment: d'oh, yeah, session_start() is being loaded ;)